# Retrieve specific contents of a column in a CSV file

Tags: tcl

I have csv file having first column as
shar-02-bc [0.49%]
rip-086-cd [0.56%]
.
.
In every cell there are 8 chars before the square braces.
Is there any method to remove the square braces and it's contents.
The modified csv file should contain the column as
shar-02-bc
rip-086-cd

Comment: First column or first row?  Also I don't see any commas, so are you sure it's *Comma-Separated Values* ?

Comment: "In every cell there are 8 chars before the square braces" -- `shar-02-bc` is 10 chars.

Answer (score 1):

If each row (not column) of the column is something like this:

```
shar-02-bc [0.49%] rip-086-cd [0.56%]
```

then you have a few options.

If you can treat each line like a list, then use `lsearch` to find the items which aren't inside square brackets (the glob pattern needs to backslash escape the square brackets)

```
lsearch -all -not -inline $line {\[*\]}
```

or you could treat each like like a dictionary with alternating key value pairs:

```
dict keys $line
```

If you treat each line like a string, then `regsub` is another option.   This replaces any non-whitespace inside square brackets with an empty string.

```
regsub -all {\[\S+\]} $line ""
```